# Minecraft mod not working on multiplayer, only on singleplayer

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

im new on this forum and making mods for minecraft, that mod that i tried to do its for the version 1.8.9 and basically it doesnt works on multiplayer, only on singleplayer, nothing works on multiplayer mode, not even the custom command that is added, heres my code

SoupCheck.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.settings.KeyBinding;
import net.minecraft.util.ChatComponentText;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumChatFormatting;
import net.minecraftforge.client.event.MouseEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.InputEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.gameevent.TickEvent;

public class SoupCheck {
    private boolean leftMouseButtonDown = false;
    private boolean isSoup = false;
    public static boolean modEnabled = false;

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onMouseClick(MouseEvent event) {
        if(modEnabled)
        {
            if (event.button == 1) { 
                leftMouseButtonDown = event.buttonstate; 
            }
        }
    }

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onTick(TickEvent.ClientTickEvent event) {
        if(modEnabled)
        {
            if (leftMouseButtonDown) { 
               //System.out.println("Botão esquerdo do mouse pressionado");
                if (Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer != null) {
                    if (Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.inventory.getCurrentItem() != null) {
                        //System.out.println("Verificando se o item é uma sopa ou uma tigela"); 
                        if (Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.inventory.getCurrentItem().getItem().getUnlocalizedName().equals("item.mushroomStew")) {
                            //System.out.println("A sopa não virou uma tigela!");
                            isSoup = true;
                        } else if (Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.inventory.getCurrentItem().getItem().getUnlocalizedName().equals("item.bowl")) {
                            //System.out.println("A sopa virou uma tigela!");
                            isSoup = false;
                        } else {
                            isSoup = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onKeyInput(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent event) {
        if(modEnabled)
        {
            if (leftMouseButtonDown) { 
                //System.out.println("Verificando se a tecla 'Q' foi pressionada"); 
                if (isSoup && Minecraft.getMinecraft().gameSettings.keyBindDrop.isPressed()) { 
                    //System.out.println("Impedindo que a tecla 'Q' seja reconhecida como pressionada");
                    unpressKey(Minecraft.getMinecraft().gameSettings.keyBindDrop);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void unpressKey(KeyBinding keyBinding) {
        if (modEnabled) {
            try {
                //System.out.println("Despressionando a tecla: " + keyBinding.getKeyDescription());
                Field pressedField = KeyBinding.class.getDeclaredField("pressed");
                pressedField.setAccessible(true);
                pressedField.setBoolean(keyBinding, false);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

SoupCheckMod.java

```
import net.minecraft.command.CommandBase;
import net.minecraft.command.ICommandSender;
import net.minecraft.util.ChatComponentText;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumChatFormatting;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLServerStartingEvent;

@Mod(modid = "nodropsoup", name = "No Drop Soup", version = "7.29.2023 - naogostodeprogramar")
public class SoupCheckMod {

    /*@Mod.EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        //System.out.println("Registrando evento Tick");
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new SoupCheck());
    }*/

    @Mod.EventHandler
    public void serverLoad(FMLServerStartingEvent event) {
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new SoupCheck());
        event.registerServerCommand(new CommandBase() {
            @Override
            public String getCommandName() {
                return "nodropsoup";
            }

            @Override
            public String getCommandUsage(ICommandSender sender) {
                return "/nodropsoup";
            }

            @Override
            public void processCommand(ICommandSender sender, String[] args) {
                if (SoupCheck.modEnabled) {
                    sender.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText(EnumChatFormatting.RED + "Mod Desativado! - by naogostodeprogramar"));
                } else {
                    sender.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText(EnumChatFormatting.GREEN + "Mod Ativado! - by naogostodeprogramar"));
                }
                SoupCheck.modEnabled = !SoupCheck.modEnabled;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

i tried on singleplayer and it worked fine, but on multiplayer didnt work nothing, and it needs to be working fine like as on singleplayer, and no im not trying to do a mod for a multiplayer server or something like that, i just want to that mod works only for me (client-side)

edit: i made a test enabling the mod in singleplayer and going to multiplayer, it works practically everything fine but the command its not being created (so i cant use /nodropsoup, it says unknown command)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _it doesnt works_. What is the code supposed to do and what is it actually doing? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Abra its a pvp mod (1.8.9), some servers for some reason while you pvp an other player and you try to eat the soup sometimes just doesnt eat the soup, this can be the fault of the server-side or client-side because of the delay, so this mod doesnt let the player drop the soup if the soup wasnt eat, that part its working, but the part of the command its not working, practically the command it was only added on singleplayer, but on multiplayer that command doesnt exist (the command is not being added), so i just need to fix that issue

Comment: If you want it to be a client side mod, why do you listen to `FMLServerStartingEvent`; a strictly server side event?